# How to create multilingual application using QML (Qt5.3) for Windows 8.1 RT?

Tags: windows, qml, qt5

I have an application based on Qt Quick 2.2. It has an English  UI. Also it has a Russian translation of UI. The app works fine on Linux and Mac OS X. I see squares instead of Russian letters on Windows 8.1 RT. I build my app as Metro app.
I use qsTr function in QML to translate strings. I also tried to write Russian text in QML files - result is the same.

p.s. Russian text is displaying correctly inside the MessageDialog in QML files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running into this bug:

[Font problem with Windows Phone 8.0](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39175)

There doesn't appear to be a complete fix yet, but there is some advice in the comments.